# Coroutines Flows being collected across Fragments

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines

I have two fragments: GeneralInformationFrament and HomeFragment, and I have one ViewModel associated for each of them. Inside both of them I have a method like:

```
private fun getInstallationSiteInformation() {
        launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
                currentFragment.getInstallationSiteOfUser(employeeId).collect {
                    when(it.status){
                        Resource.Status.LOADING -> {
                            withContext(Dispatchers.Main){
                                //Code
                            }
                        }
                        Resource.Status.SUCCESS -> {
                            withContext(Dispatchers.Main){
                                //code
                            }
                        }
                        Resource.Status.ERROR -> {
                             withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                                //more code
                             }
                        }
                    }
                }

        }
}
```

Inside each viewModel I have:

```
fun getInstallationSiteOfUser(employeeId: Int): Flow<Resource<InstallationSiteEntity?>> =
        installationSiteRepository.getInstallationSiteOfUser(employeeId).map{
                installationSiteResponse ->
            when(installationSiteResponse.status){
                Resource.Status.LOADING -> {
                    Resource.loading(null)
                }
                Resource.Status.SUCCESS -> {
                    val installationSite = installationSiteResponse.data
                    Resource.success(installationSite)
                }
                Resource.Status.ERROR -> {
                    Resource.error(installationSiteResponse.message!!, null)
                }
            }
        }
```

and in the InstallationSiteRepository I have:

```
fun getInstallationSiteOfUser(employeeId: Int): Flow<Resource<InstallationSiteEntity>> = flow{

        emit(Resource.loading(null))

        val installationSiteOfEmployee = employeesDao.getEmployeeDetailed(employeeId)

        remoteApiService.getInstallationSiteOfEmployee(employeeId).collect {apiResponse ->
            when(apiResponse){
                is ApiSuccessResponse -> {
                    apiResponse.body?.let {
                        installationSitesDao.insertInstallationSite(it.installationSite)}
                    emitAll(installationSitesDao.getInstallationSiteFromEmployeeId(employeeId).map { installationData ->
                        Resource.success(installationData)
                    })
                }
                is ApiErrorResponse -> {
                    emitAll(installationSitesDao.getInstallationSiteFromEmployeeId(employeeId).map { installationData ->
                        Resource.error(apiResponse.errorMessage, installationData)
                    })
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Soon after the transition between GeneralInformationFragment to HomeFragment the method `getInstallationSiteInformation()` is called in onViewCreated() so the behavior that I am encountering is that the flows are being collected in both fragments one after another and because one of the fragments is not available anymore I am getting a NullPointerException. My question is: When a flow source emits, every target collecting it gets the values? Is it possible what I am describing? Shouldn't the flow inside GeneralInformationFragment have been canceled and stopped receiving it ?

[EDIT 1]

In the top of my Fragments there is:

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class GeneralInformationFragment : Fragment(), CoroutineScope {

private var job = Job()
    override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext
        get() = Dispatchers.IO + job
```

And in OnDestroy() of the Fragments:

```
override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        job.cancel()
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When a flow source emits, every target collecting it gets the values?

Yes. `Flow`s are **cold** streams. They do nothing until a receiver calls `collect`. There is no restriction on multiple calls from receivers. `Flow` will emit its values for each caller.

> Shouldn't the flow inside GeneralInformationFragment have been canceled and stopped receiving it ?

You need to cancel the Flow collection. In `getInstallationSiteInformation()`, `launch(Dispatchers.IO) {/**/}` will return a `Job`. You can keep a reference to that `Job` and cancel when you want.

Alternatively, you can cancel the `CoroutineScope`.

Your `CoroutineScope` in your code is unclear, does your `Fragment` implement `CoroutineScope` maybe?

There are "out the box" `CoroutineScope`s for a `Fragment` you could use instead: `lifecycleScope` and `viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope`.

They will handle the lifecycle (cancellation) for you. `lifecycleScope` is tied to the Fragment lifecyle, whereas `viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope` is tied to the `Fragment` **View** lifecycle, `onViewCreated` to `onDestroyView`

I hope this helps at least a bit.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It clarified a lot for me. What do you think is the best approach? the way I am doing it or using viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope to cancel the coroutine?

Comment: I replaced the call launch{ //code } by viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch{//code} and that alone solved my problem. Amazing!! I don't fully understand why but maybe was because I narrowed down the possible targets for the emitter. Thanks @veritas1